# Clear white line off page

Tags: css

I need to clear the top white line on this page under the title
http://fourshireskitchens.com/kitchen-paint-palette/

Answer (score 1):

In your theme customization (Appearance > Customize) add the following CSS to the CSS-section:

```
.spb_parallax_asset {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

It should do the trick. And if you wanna remove the remaining 1px of line - add this just below the code above:

```
.spb_parallax_asset {
    border: 0;
}
```

Hope it's what you're looking for :)